# Running a Maven Webdriver Testng test on Jenkins, unidentifiable error

Tags: maven, jenkins, webdriver, testng, xvfb

Having written some tests in Java using Eclipse IDE, we want to make them run automatically after deploy. I got to the point of having just configured Maven to almost work with Jenkins, but there are some more problems. Here is one of them:
Im trying to run a headless text (xvfb, firefox) ion jenkins, but here is the output:
(I cant even identify what the problem is here)

```
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.BooleanConverter).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

Executing Maven:  -B -f /mnt/www/jenkins/jobs/Integration Tests 2/workspace/pom.xml install

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:331)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:174)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:100)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:66)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/cli/MavenLoggerManager
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.main(Maven3Launcher.java:73)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.cli.MavenLoggerManager
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:244)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:230)
    ... 19 more
channel stopped
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
hudson.util.IOException2: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:162)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:66)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:177)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:100)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:331)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:174)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/cli/MavenLoggerManager
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.main(Maven3Launcher.java:73)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.cli.MavenLoggerManager
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:244)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:230)
    ... 19 more
Finished: FAILURE
```

and this is my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.pragmaticqa.tests</groupId>
  <artifactId>functionalTests</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>functionalTests</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.32.0</version>
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>
          <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
          <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
          <version>6.8</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>xvfb</id>
                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>xvfb</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>selenium</id>
                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>start-server</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <background>true</background>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
   </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the exception trace, you are missing some classes as you are getting `ClassNotFoundException` and hence `InvocationTargetException`. There are a couple of things you can try if you haven't already.

1. Upgrade your maven
2. Configure Jenkins to use the correct Maven install

You can probably find answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388851/jenkins-unable-to-run-maven). Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you! Switched from 3.1 to 3.0.5 and the test was run successfully.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this error is covered by this bug: [JENKINS-15935](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-15935).  It was corrected in Jenkins version 1.526 and according to the changelog it doesn't seem like the fix has made it to the LTS releases yet (as of version 1.509.3).

When I ran into this error I just switched back to Maven 3.0.5 which corrected the issue for me.  I'll give Maven 3.1 another shot once I have time to update our Jenkins installs.